# How to Animate a Visual.TransformMatrix?

Tags: uwp

[TransformMatrix documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.visual.transformmatrix#Windows_UI_Composition_Visual_TransformMatrix) says "This property can be animated. Call CompositionObject.StartAnimation to associate it with a CompositionAnimation."

But I can't create a CompositionAnimation that can target it. I tried CreateQuaternionKeyframeAnimation and I tried CreateVector4KeyframeAnimation:

```
Visual visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(myUIElement);
var animation = visual.Compositor.CreateVector4KeyFrameAnimation();
Vector4 v4 = Vector4.Transform(new Vector4(), myMatrix4x4);
animation.InsertKeyFrame(1f, v4);
animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000);
visual.StartAnimation(nameof(visual.TransformMatrix), animation);
```

Which throws "The expression output does not match animating property type" as one might expect. I don't know what else to try. Do I have to create 16 separate scalar animations, one for each matrix value?  That seems a bit crazy.

EDIT:
So I tried to just roll my own and use 16 scalar animations like so:

```
for (int i = 5; i <= 20; i++)
{
    int row = (i / 4);
    int column = (i % 4);
    if (column == 0) { column = 4; }
    var matrixAnimation = visual.Compositor.CreateScalarKeyFrameAnimation();
    var matrixEasing = visual.Compositor.CreateLinearEasingFunction();
    matrixAnimation.InsertExpressionKeyFrame(1f, "this.FinalValue", matrixEasing);
    matrixAnimation.Target = nameof(visual.TransformMatrix) + ".M" + row + column;
    matrixAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(durationMilliseconds);
    visual.ImplicitAnimations[nameof(visual.TransformMatrix) + ".M" + row + column] = matrixAnimation;
}
```

So the implicit animations are created and all seems great.  Then to my dismay I write the code to change the read/write M11- M44 properties which ought to trigger the implicit animation and I get a compiler error:

> "Cannot modify the return value of 'Visual.TransformMatrix' because it
>   is not a variable".

And assigning it a new Matrix4x4 does not trigger the implicit animation.

Comment: I've helped you report this issue to the relevant team. They're investigating it.

Comment: Just to clarify I'm using keyframe implicit animations. I heaven't dug in and learned expression animations yet, but perhaps that's the only way to do it.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT any update?

Comment: @Muzib Please see the response on the MSDN thread [How to Animate Visual.TransformationMatrix Property Using Composition API?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adfaf380-0bb1-4905-8b1f-6d3c87da71ee/uwphow-to-animate-visualtransformationmatrix-property-using-composition-api?forum=wpdevelop).