# Storyboard Animation of UIElement.PlaneProjection Broken When Composition API Used at All

Tags: uwp

I'm using the Composition API for various animations and effects. I'm also trying to incorporate the [3D perspective effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/3-d-perspective-effects) on the same elements. Unfortunately the only way to recreate a 3D perspective effect with Composition API is using the Visual.TransformMatrix property which [can't be animated AFAIK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53273936/how-to-animate-a-visual-transformmatrix?noredirect=1#comment93549390_53273936). So for an animatable 3D perspective effect I have to use regular Storyboard that targets a PlaneProjection as shown in the first link.

The problem (which took me a very long time to discover the cause of) is that when the Storyboard completed, it reverted to its original value. FillBehavior was set to its default 'HoldEnd.'  Calling 'Storyboard.GetCurrentState()' showed it was 'Filling' but it really wasn't.

Then I realized this broken behavior only occurs if ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual has been called on the UIElement. Even if I don't change any of the Visual's properties or do anything with it at all, simply calling that makes it effectively impossible to use a Storyboard animation that targets UIElement.PlaneProjection if you don't want it to reset upon completion.

Copying and pasting the code below in a new UWP project targeting 1809 or 1803 will provide a full repro project.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="PlaneProjectionStoryboardBugRepro.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="Transparent">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <TextBlock x:Name="StandardText" Visibility="Visible" Foreground="DarkGreen" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="100" FontSize="24">
            Press the rotate button several times<LineBreak/>
            Notice Storyboard that is rotating the plane projection about Y axis is working properly.<LineBreak/>
            Now try it after pressing the second button.
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="WarningText" Visibility="Collapsed" Foreground="DarkRed" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="100" FontSize="24">
            Composition API has been invoked.<LineBreak/>
            Notice that now the rotation Storyboard animation's FillBehavior is broken.<LineBreak/>
            Simply from calling 'ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual'
        </TextBlock>
        <Image x:Name="Logo" Source="Assets\StoreLogo.png"  Height="500" Width="500" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="30">
            <Button Content="Rotate Logo" Margin="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <Button Content="Call 'GetElementVisual' On Logo" Margin="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
            <Button Content="Reset" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="12" Click="Button_Click_3"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Hosting;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace PlaneProjectionStoryboardBugRepro
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var pp = new PlaneProjection();
            Logo.Projection = pp;
        }

        double EndAngle = 0;

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            EndAngle = (EndAngle == 0) ? 45 : 0;
            var storyboard = new Storyboard();
            var animation = new DoubleAnimation();
            animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
            animation.To = EndAngle;
            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, Logo);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)");
            storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
            storyboard.Begin();
        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Simply instantiating a Visual object of the UIElement breaks the Storyboard.
            var visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(Logo);

            StandardText.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            WarningText.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        async void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await CoreApplication.RequestRestartAsync("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tested in my device os version 1803, and the state of storyboard is always `Active` but not `Filling`, I don't know how do you get the state of storyboard. Please show more detail.

Comment: I didn't include a Storyboard.GetCurrentState() in the test project but adding it now... It says Filling. Yours doesn't?

Comment: The workaround for me is to simply wrap any UIElement I'm animating with Grid and only use PlaneProjection animations on that.

Comment: [Here is](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnGu-7rqGecsgZIKDi4kbPVMnrxyxw) an updated version of the project that shows the Storyboard state.